# Check Node in TreeView Control in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, file-listing

How can I check that the selected Node is a **File** or **directory** in a `TreeView` Control in C#?

I am working on window form in C#.
I can check through the file extension but there are so many file extensions so it makes for a lengthy code. Can any body give me a small method for this?

Comment: That would depend on how you populated your TreeView control.

Comment: post some code to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `node.GetType()` property of the particular node to find out that it is directory or file. I.e.:

```
if (tree.SelectedNode.GetType() == typeof(FileNode))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tag` property of the [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to store information about node type - for example store there enum value, object or any other type that will be useful for you.